# Jquery change new date() value by days

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tinkered a simple weekly list and I have done some paging function. Being newbie and learning my way through I got stuck as I only can pick up the present day and not too familiar yet with date formatting/manipulating. So I am asking the GOOD people to put me on the right track.

Could someone guide me in the right direction please? The code kind of works but I only can move 7 days backwards or forwards from today. Also as this is my first calendar type of code any other suggestions are more than welcome how to make it more accurate.

The purpose of this calendar that by selecting each days a php file will appear at the bottom with some information from MySQL database, where all the dates are stored in UNIX format.

Thanks for your input in advance and here is the bit of the code that I am stuck on:

```
    <script>
    var today = new Date();

    function movedate(n){
        for(count=0;count<7;count++){
            var f_actdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() -today.getDay()+ count+1+n));
            $("#day"+count).html(f_actdate);
            //change the global today ???
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#pre").click(function(){
        movedate(-7);
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#after").click(function(){
        movedate(7);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Well done for downvoting the question very human being. I have been working on days by myself learning it. Then I came to ask the good people's help. so total I spent hours to put everything together and you not even bothered to type a word why you down voting it. Very negative attitude and I am sorry for those people who only use the arrow buttons... off the topic sorry

Comment: Frequently people get turned off by questions with long code snippets which fail to at least provide some hint what might be wrong. You should try to reduce the amount of code you are presenting by eliminating stuff that is less likely to cause the issue. It will make things more productive for both sides.

Comment: @holodoc thanks for the advice. I can take out a big chunk of it but it would only answer one of my question. I take the point and I guess I have to live with it. I do think using only the arrows should only be allowed with some comments as no one can read other people mind yet:)

Comment: @holodoc sorry I am still off the topic, but I rather would like to focus on the issue that I am stuck with. I would greatly appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: Well of course you can only move 7 days.. your code only says 7! `movedate(-7);` and `movedate(7);`.  You have not shown how you tried to  fix the problem. This will be one reason why you got downvoted.

Comment: @JK. thanks for the comments. I needed to change the today variable that I didn't know how to. A little bit of research and many tries finally got me going again. See my answer later. And yes I am moving it by 7 because  I like to shows the dates by weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few other tries I have found the solution that required:

```
function movedate(n){
        for(count=0;count<7;count++){
            var f_actdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() -today.getDay()+ count+1+n));
            $("#day"+count).html(f_actdate);
        }
        **today.setDate(today.getDate()+n);**
    }
```